# How to give file name as current date in expect

Tags: bash, date, expect

I have wrote a script in expect as follows. I want to give date as variable to cd command but when I am giving the date as variable to the command and it add '' commas and therefore it shows a error as follows. How to get rid of those commas?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#!/bin/bash

set DATE [exec date +%c]
set DATE2 [exec date +'%Y%m%d']


log_user 0
log_file -a /lch/portal/scripts/sftpcheck21/log/sftpcheck21.log
send_log "test ran on $DATE \n"
spawn sftp -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "Port=8022" lchsftp22@lch.com@sftapx21
expect "lchsftp22@lch.com@sftapx21's password:"
send "London@123\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /PIMCOXXX_FDM/SwapClear/$DATE2\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /lch/portal/scripts/sftpcheck21\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get 'P-PSWC-PIMCOXXX_FDM-$DATE2-233518_$DATE2_REP000F1d - Trade Level Pricing_ 1.TXT'\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
log_file
```

output as follows

```
sftp> cd /PIMCOXXX_FDM/SwapClear/'20220130'
Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or director
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes have no special meaning in expect or Tcl. Normally [the shell will remove those](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal), but Tcl does not.

There are builtin ways to get the date in expect:

1. use the Tcl [`clock`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm) command

   ```
   set DATE [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d]
   ```
2. use the expect [`timestamp`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/expect.1.html) command

   ```
   set DATE [timestamp -format %Y%m%d]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the script as follows and it resolved the problem

```
#!/bin/bash

set DATE [exec date +%c]
#set DATE2 [exec date +'%Y%m%d']
#set DATE3 [ exec /bin/date -d "yesterday" +%Y%m%d]
#set DATE3 [ exec /bin/date -d "-4 day" +%Y%m%d]
set DATE3 [ exec /bin/date -d "today"  +%Y%m%d]

log_user 0
log_file -a /lch/portal/scripts/sftpcheck21/log/sftpcheck21.log
send_log "test ran on $DATE \n"
spawn sftp -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "Port=8022" lchsftp22@lch.com@sftapx21
expect "lchsftp22@lch.com@sftapx21's password:"
send "London@123\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /PIMCOXXX_FDM/SwapClear/$DATE3\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd /lch/portal/scripts/sftpcheck21\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get 'P-PSWC-PIMCOXXX_FDM-$DATE3-233518_$DATE3\_REP000F1d - Trade Level Pricing_ 1.TXT'\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
log_file
```

In the line `send "get 'P-PSWC-PIMCOXXX_FDM-$DATE3-233518_$DATE3\_REP000F1d - Trade Level Pricing_ 1.TXT'\n` used \ as delimiter for varible DATE3

Comment: You could also brace the variables: `send "get 'P-PSWC-PIMCOXXX_FDM-${DATE3}-233518_${DATE3}_REP000F1d...`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation